# Custom quantity on woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I sell screws online on a small Woocommerce shop, and because i'm selling screws i need to sell prederminated quantity (5, 10, 60, 155, 300).

Since I can't code i've tried to search online for a free plugin, but I can find almost zero information about it and i was wondering if someone could help me solve the problem via php

Comment: If you sell them in packages of those sizes, you could just make a variable product and use "quantity" as the defining attribute.

Comment: Screws are not in packages, i can't use a variable and call it "quantity" since in doesn't deduct the "quantity" from the stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

In your specific case [WooCommerce Fixed Quantity](https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-fixed-quantity/installation/) will do the job. Leave a comment if you need some help with configuration.

--

You should try harder. [WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-incremental-product-quantities/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: With this plugin i can determinate a max. and min. quantity or just an incremental ammount of screws.
I can't set a step with my quantity (5, 10, 60, 155, 300), any suggestion?

Comment: Yeah, a little help would be greatly appreciated : )
Any idea on how to set the quantity description template on woocommerce>setting>products>fixed quantity

Comment: I think you should use only `{qty}`. After this you have to fill form Fixed Quantity Price in product page.

Comment: I think there's a problem with this plugin, i'm using wordpress 4.7 and there's no "Fixed quantity prices" on the product page

Comment: I'm also using wp 4.7 and `Fixed Quantity Price` is displaying properly under `Advanced` settings in `Product Data` box .

Comment: There we go!
I could not see "fixed quantity price" because the item was set on "variable product", now it's set on "simple product" and everything work fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Quantities and Units for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quantities-and-units-for-woocommerce/)  plugin.

Comment: With this plugin i can determinate a max. and min. quantity or just an incremental ammount of screws.
I can't set a step with my quantity (5, 10, 60, 155, 300), any suggestion?